# MediaRecorder Video Quality

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I need to capture the video from old camera api and upload it to the server but problem is video file size is very big to upload when i capture. So i just want to ask what video quality should i set to MediaRecorder that file size is not too big to upload to the server and video quality is not too low. Following are the available video qualities in CamcorderProfile

```
/**
     * Quality level corresponding to the lowest available resolution.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_LOW  = 0;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the highest available resolution.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_HIGH = 1;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the qcif (176 x 144) resolution.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_QCIF = 2;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the cif (352 x 288) resolution.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_CIF = 3;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the 480p (720 x 480) resolution.
     * Note that the horizontal resolution for 480p can also be other
     * values, such as 640 or 704, instead of 720.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_480P = 4;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the 720p (1280 x 720) resolution.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_720P = 5;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the 1080p (1920 x 1080) resolution.
     * Note that the vertical resolution for 1080p can also be 1088,
     * instead of 1080 (used by some vendors to avoid cropping during
     * video playback).
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_1080P = 6;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the QVGA (320x240) resolution.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_QVGA = 7;

    /**
     * Quality level corresponding to the 2160p (3840x2160) resolution.
     */
    public static final int QUALITY_2160P = 8;
```